# TypeError: iterator1.next is not a function

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic2

## **In blank Ionic Prjoect**

I am getting an exception, when I add the firebase script

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.1.0/firebase.js"></script>
```

to my empty Ionic 2 Beta.10 project

Copying error log from Chrome:

EXCEPTION: Error in ./MyApp class MyApp - inline template:0:9

```
browser_adapter.js:77 TypeError: iterator1.next is not a function
at Object.areIterablesEqual (collection.js:314)
at Object.devModeEqual (change_detection_util.js:9)
at checkBinding (view_utils.js:125)
at DebugAppView._View_MyApp0.detectChangesInternal (MyApp.template.js:38)
at DebugAppView.AppView.detectChanges (view.js:234)
at DebugAppView.detectChanges (view.js:339)
at DebugAppView.AppView.detectViewChildrenChanges (view.js:260)
at DebugAppView.AppView.detectChangesInternal (view.js:245)
at DebugAppView.AppView.detectChanges (view.js:234)
at DebugAppView.detectChanges (view.js:339)
```

[image: Error in image]

**Note :This is working in Mac System Chrome without any Exceptions but in linux Chrome it's giving this Exceptions.**

My system configurations:

Cordova CLI: 6.2.0

Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-beta.10

Ionic CLI Version: 2.0.0-beta.32

Ionic App Lib Version: 2.0.0-beta.18

OS: Distributor ID: Ubuntu Description: Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS 

Node Version: v5.6.0

gulp version:3.9.1

**Solved the issue:**
In your index.html place the contents under the  <body> tag like this:

```
<script src="build/js/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
<script src="build/js/Reflect.js"></script>
<script src="build/js/zone.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/live/3.0/firebase.js"></script>
<script src="build/js/app.bundle.js"></script>
```

Comment: This error is coming from a `.next()` function somewhere in an imported package. It is probably because `iterator1` is undefined. Have you tried locating `iterator1.next` in the chrome debugger?

Comment: you are going to need to show a bit more code... there is nothing here that is very helpful at this point.

Comment: I use an es6 require to import firebase `let firebase = require('firebase');` and then removed the `<script>` import from index.html and it resolved the issue for me.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I am coming across the exact same issue. It seems to have occurred since I've updated Chrome.

Comment: @dazziola. I solved the issue  i edit the post it's a small problem .. it may helpful to you

Comment: @Aida that worked for me. Thank you for your help! Have you any understanding as to why they now need to be in this order? Thanks again!